# Sorting strings using Ordered[String] in Scala?

Tags: scala

I need to have an equivalent of the `compareWith(a,b)` method in Java, in Scala.

I have a list of strings and I need to sort them by comparing them with each other. `sortBy` just takes one string and returns a score, but that's not enough in my case, i need to compare two strings with each other and then return a number based on which one is better.

It seems like the only option is to write a custom case class, convert the strings to it, and then covert them back. For performance reasons, I want to avoid this as I have a large amount of data to process.

Is there a way to do this with just the strings?

Comment: `compareWith()`? I'm having a hard time finding the documentation for that. Can you provide a link? Also, I'm not sure what's wrong with `"abc" compareTo "xyz"`. Please clarify.

Comment: It was `compareTo` rather than with, I haven't used java in a while. And what's wrong is that I need to write my own rules for the comparison.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I couldn't find it. As for `compareTo()`, I guess I still don't understand your objections and/or requirements. When it comes to sorting a `List[String]`, you can `.sortWith(_.compareTo(_)<0)` (which you seem to like), or you can `.sortBy(s=>s)` (which is shorter), or you can `.sorted` (which is direct and to the point).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`sortWith`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html#sortWith(lt:(A,A)=%3EBoolean):Repr).

> `sortWith(lt: (A, A) ⇒ Boolean): Repr`
>
> Sorts this sequence according to a comparison function.
>
> Note: will not terminate for infinite-sized collections.
>
> The sort is stable. That is, elements that are equal (as determined by lt) appear in the same order in the sorted sequence as in the original.
>
> `lt` the comparison function which tests whether its first argument precedes its second argument in the desired ordering.

Example:

```
List("Steve", "Tom", "John", "Bob").sortWith(_.compareTo(_) < 0) =
List("Bob", "John", "Steve", "Tom")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `.sorted` will do the trick.